# The dimension of the normal cone of a face in a polytope

Tags: convex-polytopes, convex-geometry, polyhedra, polygons, fans

Let $P$ is a polytope in $\mathbb{R}^n$ if $F$ is one of its faces of dimension $d$ then the dimension of its normal cone $\mathcal{N}(F)$ is $n-d$.\

This seems to be intuitively obvious but I can't write an explicit proof of it.
Such an statement is written as one of the properties of normal fans on Wikipedia [(here)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_fan)  and as a reference it suggests the book "Lectures on Polytopes" by Ziegler, I searched a lot in his book but I couldn't find such an statement, maybe since I am really new in this field and I don't know much it is stated somehow indirectly and one can deduce this from some other statement.
I would be really grateful if someone can help me to find an explicit proof for this statement.

Comment: Do you know the fact that the poset of cones in the normal fan (under inclusion) is dual to the poset of faces of the polytope? The result you want follows immediately from this stronger claim.

Comment: Do you mean the fact that: The face lattice of a polytope is anti-isomorphic to the one of its dual? I've seen such a thing in some references but it's not that clear to me how you deduce the answer to my question from this one. Can you give me more hint? Do you know a good reference for such a question? Actually in the reference I found this a dual polytope to a fixed polytope P is defined to be the one whose face lattice is anti isomorphic to that of P, and I guess this way of defining a dual polytope may not lead to such a fact about dimension of the normal cone.

Comment: What you said is closely related, yes. All of these claims are straightforward to prove from the definitions.

Comment: Try Gaku Liu’s notes on polytopes: https://sites.google.com/view/gakuliu

Comment: Also posted on [M.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4243418/415941).

Answer (score 2):

Let $f\subset P$ be a proper face of dimension $d$. Let $v_0,...,v_m\in P$ be an enumeration of the vertices of $P$, so that $v_0,...,v_r$ are the vertices of $f$.

I assume that it is known that the normal vectors of $f$ form a convex cone. So it remains to verify that the dimension of this cone is $n-d$.

Consider a basis $e_1,...,e_n\in\Bbb R^n$ for which

- $e_1,...,e_d$ are parallel to $f$, more precisely, w.l.o.g. assume that $e_i=v_i-v_0$,
- $e_{d+1},...,e_n$ are orthogonal to $f$, and
- $e_{d+1}$ is a normal vector to $f$.

The latter point means that $\def\<{\langle} \def\>{\rangle} \<e_{d+1},v_i-v_0\>=0$ exactly for $i\in\{0,...,r\}$. We now show that $e_{d+1}+\epsilon e_i$ is also a normal vector to $f$ for all sufficiently small $|\epsilon|$ if and only if $i\in\{d+1,...,n\}$, establishing dimension $n-d$ for the normal cone.

For $i\in\{1,...,d\}$, since $\<e_{d+1}+\epsilon e_i,v_i-v_0\>=\epsilon\|v_i-v_0\|^2 \not=0$ whenever $\epsilon\not=0$, we see that the normal cone to $f$ must be orthogonal to $e_i$. In particular, its dimension must be at most $n-d$.

On the other hand, assume $i\in\{d+1,...,n\}$.
If $j\in\{0,...,r\}$, then $e_i$ is orthogonal to $v_j-v_0$ and $\<e_{d+1}+\epsilon e_i,v_j-v_0\>= \<e_{d+1},v_j-v_0\>=0$ as before.
And if $j\in\{r+1,...,m\}$, then $\<e_{d+1},v_j-v_0\><0$ and so $\<e_{d+1}+\epsilon e_i,v_j-v_0\>$ is still negative as long as $|\epsilon|$ is small enough. That means $e_{d+1}+\epsilon e_i$ is still a normal vector to $f$, and the normal cone of $f$ has a proper expansion in the direction of $e_i$, making it $(n-d)$-dimensional.